# How to give permission to two sharepoint list to two user one should not view other

Tags: list, sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-designer

I have to create two lists called `List1` and `List2` and two users `user1` and `user2` respectively. I want to restrict lists based on users. For example, if `List1` is assigned to `user1` he is not supposed to view `List2`, and a similar way `user2` should not view `List1`.

I would appreciate if I get help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use audience targeting , choose your target user in audience targeting section. Your list will be visible to the user you will select only.

Please follow the below steps:

[edit your list view web part : click edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xtiK.png)

[Go to list view webpart:click edit webpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baIlL.png)

[click advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXchj.png)

[In target Audience , enter your require user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fATWr.png)